# How to create services with session tokens in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, security

I have a multi-tenant web mapping application running on ArcGIS server. I am trying to replace with geoserver. Identity of the users for tenants are maintained through another identity api. After successful login Api generates the session token through get token service for a user passing the fixed credentials. Geoserver provides Digest and http header method- but is there a way to generate unique tokens for every session- so that no information related to user authentication is hard coded in client side code and all the communication between client application and geoserver is happening with a session token similar to this:
https://xxxxx/rest/services/xxxxx/MapServer/export?bbox=xxxxx&size=1393%2C85&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=truelayers=show%3A1&token=**2Cj8mUHLD5jD2fNNZ8SO-bP-94**.&f=image

Comment: Have you read through http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/ ? please update your question with what you have tried so far and what is not working for you

Comment: I have been looking - but so far have not found anything unique to session.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution, have you found any yet?

Comment: Have you guys found a solution? I need to implement the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a community plugin for `authkey`:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html

> A sample authenticated request looks like:
>   http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&authkey=ef18d7e7-963b-470f-9230-c7f9de166888